# Finding grok pattern for Log file

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have a log file in the following format :

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 30
```

I tried to write a grok file, but am not able to correctly encode the `= 30` part of the expression.

This is my implmentation so far :

```
%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}.%{WORD:word3}|%{SPACE:space}%{URIPARAM:sign}%{SPACE:space}%{NONNEGINT:num}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope either of these two pattern will help to solve your problem.

`%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}.%{WORD:word3} = %{INT:number}`

or

`%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}.%{WORD:word3}\s\S\s%{INT:number}`

I have used grok debugger https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to create the pattern. Here is the screenshot of the output.

[image]